# Nested serializer with custom queryset

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to display the custom query values to the nested serializer . But its not displaying

**serializer.py**

```
class TueRangeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = SubnetRange
        fields = ('type', 'id', 'begin', 'end')


class TueSubnetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    range = TueRangeSerializer(required=False,read_only=False,many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Subnet
        fields = ('name','base_address','bits','range')


    def create(self,validated_data):
        print(validated_data)
```

And in the api file

**api.py**

```
class SubnetList(APIView):


    def get(self, request, format=None):

        query = 'SELECT ss.id ,ssr.id, ssp.id , ' \
                ' ss.name as name, ss.bits as bits, ssr.begin as begin FROM subnets_subnet ss' \
                ' inner join subnets_subnetphysical ssp on ssp.subnet_id = ss.id' \
                ' inner join subnets_subnetrange ssr on ssr.subnet_physical_id = ssp.id'

        subnets = Subnet.objects.raw(query)
        serializer = TueSubnetSerializer(subnets,many=True)

        return Response(serializer.data)
```

SQL query is correct. But on the response of the serializer its displaying only the data from subnets table

**Result**

```
[
    {
        "name": "First subnet",
        "base_address": "192.100.30.0",
        "bits": 24
    },
    {
        "name": "Second subnet",
        "base_address": "192.100.30.0",
        "bits": 24
    }    
]
```

Its not displaying the range output